# error archivo externo .txt Python

Tags: python, txt

Hola buenos dias tengo este problema el programa no me genera el archivo externo .txt cual puede ser el error?

```
from io import open 

archivo_externo=open("primerArchivo.txt","w")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la función `open` es nativa de python, no tienes que importarla

Comment: perdón es que estoy aprendiendo y el profesor lo explica así  en el video

Comment: ¿El pantallazo es necesario? ¿qué significa que _no te genera_? ¿Hay un error? ¿cuál es el mensaje exacto de error?. Mejor lee [ask], ya que tu pregunta requiere de muchas aclaraciones... Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Para crear el archivo en python solo debes utilizar la función open ya que como te dicen arriba esta función es nativa de python:

```
file = open("C:/mosquitto/code/tuarchivo.txt", "w")
file.write("Hello world");
print("archivo creado...")
file.close()
```

Comment: Cual es el propósito del modulo os en este código?

Comment: ninguno, corrijo la respuesta